# Rails attr_accesssible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am very new to rails, but not so much to web development. I am currently working through teamtreehouse's Build a Simple Rails application and they are using Rails 3, whereas I am using rails 4.

In the status.rb which allows the users to post a status I have the following class:

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :content, :user_id
    belongs_to :user
end
```

I appreciate that attr_accessible has been removed from rails 4 and now using params, but any reading I do, it requires the class name to change. Does anybody have any ideas on how I can make this work?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, 'class name to change'?

Comment: So for example, if the class was originally person, they were renaming the class PeoplePerams. I'm sorry if that isn't good enough response but that is all I know

Comment: The class isn't renamed to PeopleParams, you're misunderstanding slightly. Look here, you add a method to the controller http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You remove this line from the model.

```
attr_accessible :content, :user_id
```

Then in the controller you add a method to white list the parameters that can be mass-assigned.

```
 def status_params
   params.require(:status).permit(:content, :user_id)
 end
```

And you use that to create a new Status

```
def create
  Status.create(status_params)
end
```

More in the docs http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Answer (score 1):

As you said in rails 4 attr_accessible is removed and we use strong params. To make above code work in rails 4 you'll need to make a private method status_params in your status_controller and then while creating a status or updating a status you can pass that method in params like this:

```
class PeopleController < ActionController::Base 
  def create
    @status = Status.new(status_params)
    @status.save
  end
  private
    def status_params
      params.require(:status).permit(:content, :user_id)
    end
end
```

We are not changing any class here, rails 4 has simply moved the attribute accessible logic to controllers from the model. For more details read about [strong parameter](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add gem 'protected_attributes' to your projects gemfile and bundle install. 'protected_attributes' gem gives you the ability to use attr_accessible and attr_protected (like in rails 3 apps) in a rails 4 app.

However, I would recommend to focus on learning how to properly use strong_params as it is important and pretty straight forward. Refer to the Ruby-on-Rails guides for detailed explanations of strong_params and controllers in general.

Also, I'd recommend that you find and use newer tutorials that are on Rails 4, there are no shortage. There are many differences between Rails 3 and 4, some of which aren't apparent on the surface and especially not to a beginner. In terms of learning, the way to go is to learn how to build a rails app with one version of the framework and to do with resources/tutorials etc that are meant for that version of Rails. As a beginner, there is no good reason for unnecessarily adding the complexity of needing to account for the intricacies and differences of Rails 3 and 4.